# playframework jpa get entity with two conditions

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0, entity

I am trying to create method that will select from db user. I am giving to paramets (email and password)
    I find some code that do what I wont. But it works only in ebean not JPA. And I am using JPA+hibernate
here is the code in ebean:

```
return find.where()
        .eq("email", email)
        .eq("password", password)
        .findUnique();
```

Please help me creating question like this in JPA. 
I need this to create login validation on app.

Any help apreaceate

EDIT
Throwing Error if no suitable user find in db

```
try {
    authenticatedUser = query.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("new way of loggin  " + authenticatedUser);
} catch (Exceptione) {
    authenticatedUser = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have configured JPA correctly and you can access the EntityManager like:

```
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
..
JPA.em();
```

You should be able to create a similar query to the one with ebean (assuming your entity is User):

```
TypedQuery<User> query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email and u.password= :password", User.class);
query.setParameter("email", email);
query.setParameter("password", password);
User u = query.getSingleResult();
```

You should also validate exceptions (eg: not found).

Comment: WHat kind of exception should I throw if there will be no suitable user? See above

Comment: NoResultException if no result was found or NonUniqueResultException if multiple results are found.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult()

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way:

```
    /**
 * Retrive custom user by email and password
 * @param email
 * @param password
 */
@Transactional
public static User getCustomUser(String email, String password)   {
    User authorisedUser = null;
    List<User> authenticatedUser = (List<User>) JPA.em()
            .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email='" + email + "' AND password='" + password + "' ", User.class)
            .getResultList();
    for (int i=0;i<authenticatedUser.size();i++) {
        authorisedUser = authenticatedUser.get(i);
    }
    return authorisedUser;
}
```

Comment: Don't do it that way - and I mean NEVER. By setting attributes like that you can get sql injections. Do it like in my answer.

You can also choose between native sql queries and jpql queries.

Also you'll only have 1 user with that email (or at least that's what makes sense) so you should not retrieve a list but a single result. Just like in my answer.